# how do we create a list of random gps locations in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

is there any way we can create a X number of locations(latitude and longitude) which is inside a radius of 500 meters to your current gps location and save it into a list.
i am really a beginner and  trying to do understand the logic of calculating the latitude and longitude calculating methods.

Answer (score 1):

Earth can be approximated as a sphere.

With the pythagorean theorem, we can get `dx` and `dy` from the maximum distance of 500 meters, e.g. 200m and 300m should give ~360m (`sqrt((200×200)+(300×300))`).

Put that into [coordinates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var berlin = new GeoCoordinate(52.520008, 13.404954); // degrees
var earthRadius = 6378137.0; // meters
var dx = 200.0; // meters
var dy = 300.0; // meters
var lat2 = berlin.Latitude + (180/Math.PI) * (dx/earthRadius);
var lon2 = berlin.Longitude + (180/Math.PI) * (dy/earthRadius) / Math.Cos(berlin.Latitude);
var closeToBerlin = new GeoCoordinate(lat2, lon2);
Console.WriteLine(berlin.GetDistanceTo(closeToBerlin));
```

The output is 351 meters, so it's a pretty close estimation in this case. That probably works for a few kilometers as well.

Todos for you:

1. Make a loop for how many coordinates you need
2. Create a random number for the distance below 500m
3. Create a random number for `dx`
4. Calculate `dy` from `dx`
5. Use above code to generate a `GeoCoordinate`
6. Put them into a list.

Comment: For the delta you could/should use a `UnityEngine.Vector2` in order to be able to use unity built-in vector math ... then you can do something like e.g. `var d  =`[`Vector2.ClampMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.ClampMagnitude.html)`(new Vector2(`[`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)`(0f, 500f), Random.Range(0f, 500f)), 500f);` so you get a random direction with a maximum delta of 500 meters

Comment: Oh actually it goes even simpler ^^ You can also use a [`Random.insideUnitCircle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html) and do e.g. `var d = Random.insideUnitCircle * 500f`